# To determine whether the original source file contained a function call?

Tags: assembly, arm

just wondering if a source file containing a valid sequence of ARM assembly instructions (e.g. code.S) is “assembled” into binary machine code by the assembler program in the usual fashion (say there will be many more 0s and 1s than that) and If you cannot see the original source file code.S but you can see the binary machine code output, is it possible to determine whether the original source file contained a function call?! 
Thanks

Comment: Hi, Why did you add the Python tag ?

Comment: objdump? https://manpages.debian.org/testing/binutils-arm-linux-gnueabi/arm-linux-gnueabi-objdump.1.en.html

Comment: I don't think Python is an appropriate language for this.

Comment: Disassemble it and look for `bl` and `blx` instructions.  Those are function calls.  (Possibly to other functions inside the same executable, or possibly to PLT stubs for external library functions...)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, but you'll need to compile your application with debug enabled. This type of information is contained in the DWARF debug sections; it's not part of a non-debug ELF executable.

Comment: but like what will be the line of coding required in ARM assembly if any to determine whether the original source file contained a function call from a binary output ?!

Comment: You'd need to read the full debug info (large and complex) to determine file name mapping, and then disassemble the binary to look for branches.

Function calls via dynamic function pointer might be a problem.